# Trying to use external Javascript library in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, slick.js

I'm aware there are similar questions but I still can not get it to work..

So I want to use [slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) so I downloaded the files and put it in my assets folder in my angular application

Ive imported the libraries in my

**angular.cli.json**

```
"styles": [
    "./assets/scripts/slick-1.8.0/slick.css",
    "./assets/scripts/slick-1.8.0/slick-theme.css"
],
"scripts": [
    //jQuery imports above
    "./assets/scripts/slick-1.8.0/slick.min.js"
]
```

then In my component...

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponentBase } from '@shared/common/app-component-base';
import * as Slick from '../../../../assets/scripts/slick-1.8.0/slick/slick.min.js';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-di-type2',
    templateUrl: './di-type2.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./di-type2.component.scss']
})

export class DiType2Component extends AppComponentBase implements OnInit {

   public constructor(
    injector: Injector
   ) {
     super(injector);
   }

   ngOnInit() {
      const slideContainer = document.querySelector('.slider');
      slideContainer.slick({
         autoplay: true,
         autoplaySpeed: 3500,
      });
   }

}
```

from what Ive read about importing external javascript libraries into angular application this should work.. Im getting an error in vscode that says `[ts] Property 'slick' does not exist on type 'Element'.any`

and then in my console im getting

[image]

any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: a TypeError might mean that the types for Slick are not found, so the compiler does not know that .slick is a function. Do you have a `.d.ts` file for the javascript library?

Comment: Slickjs needs jquery object change  document.querySelector('.slider'); to $('.slider'). you should also have jquery in your stack.

Comment: But using jQuery DOM selection is highly discouraged in Angular, since you should use Angular to handle the DOM for you. You can use Angular data binding and transitions to create an image slider. Perhaps you can find an existing Angular image slider component.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the library as a var of type "any" (assuming it has no typing definitions *.d.ts) after your imports in your component if you import the script in your index.html:

```
declare let <yourlib>: any;
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Slick.js using Node and NPM

> https://nodejs.org/

```
npm install slick-carousel --save
```

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/slick-carousel

Once you install this npm, it'll be saved as a dependency in your package.json file.

Then import Slick:

```
import 'slick-carousel';

someElement.slick();
```